# Different color in Vim while using screen

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, color-scheme, xterm, iterm

I'm currently using color scheme from http://vimcolors.com/535/jay/dark in iTerm on Mac OSX. However, I found the color became different when I use Vim in screen, what setting should I look into here?

Without screen:

[image]

With screen:

[image]

```
> echo $TERM
xterm-256color
> cat ~/.screenrc
...
term xterm-256color
```

Comment: I think inside screen you have to set `TERM=screen-256color`.

Comment: Do you mean that I should put term ```screen-256color``` in screenrc instead of term ```xterm-256color```? Nope, the problem remain the same.

Comment: ```term "screen-256color"``` solved my problem, double quotes are needed here

Answer (score 0):

I hope it isn't too late.

Normally, on your ~/.vimrc there might be a line

```
colorscheme yourColorScheme
```

where yourColorScheme is one of the .vim color configuration file your can find in /usr/share/vim/vim80/colors/, without the .vim extension
Example, I want to use /usr/share/vim/vim80/colors/blue.vim configuration file, I do

```
colorscheme blue
```

If this line isn't written in .vimrc, then vim will select a default color configuration file and that selection might be different while using screen.

I had the same problem and solve it by adding this line à the end of the file.

The only distasteful thing is that you will probably have to try all the configuration listed in /usr/share/vim/vim80/colors/ to find the one you liked (I advise you to open a terminal with your ~/.vimrc opened in to test the differents colorshemes, a second terminal where you vim a file that shows you the good syntax color you like, and a third and a third where you launch screen and vim the same file to see the new syntax color and compare)